# Comparar dentro de una subconsulta mysql

Tags: mysql, subconsultas

En la subconsulta del join calculo cada uno de los meses, me gustaría poder comparar a.id dentro de la subconsulta, esto con el fin de optimizarla. estoy usando MySQL

```
select m.*, a.*
from (select * from anticipos where producto.id = 50) as a
join (
    select 
    SUM(cantidad) from meses 
    where mes BETWEEN 1 and 5 
    GROUP BY detalles
) as m on a.id = m.anticipo_id
```

Intenté hacer lo siguiente pero no funciona evidentemente, hay algún modo de realizarlo?

```
join (
    select SUM(cantidad) 
    from meses 
    where a.id = anticipo_id AND mes BETWEEN 1 and 5 
    GROUP BY detalles
) as m on a.id = m.anticipo_id
```

PDT: Omití datos en el select para que sea mas entendible lo que necesito.

Comment: A ver si entendemos mejor: a.id es columna de anticipos? El mundo de la subconsulta no puede ver lo que está afuera, es un resultSet que vas a armar ANTES DE resolver el join con `a`.

Comment: Si, exacto a como lo dices, es que ahorita el select del join calcula todo lo que hay en la tabla meses, y es mucho trabajo, entonces quiero que solo calcule con cierto anticipo_id

Comment: Sigue sin ser claro cuál valor de anticipo_id debería usar. No es claro que el subconjunto que denominas `a` tenga UNA fila. Pueden ser N. No conozco tu negocio :) Será que con hacer el join entre anticipos y meses de una buena vez, sin subconsulta y con las condiciones, funciona? Lo otro: no es claro que a anticipos le pongas una condición `producto.id = 50` porque en ninguna parte hay tabla producto en la subconsulta de `a`